Why do the tablets say "זכור את" and "כבד את" instead of "זכור" and "כבד"?

In the common representation of the Mosaic Tablets, why do they say "זכור את" and "כבד את" instead of "זכור" and "כבד"?

The artist appears to have chosen the first two words of each דבר.

Because that's what's written in the Torah?

Come on, he is asking why do we use את, there is an aggadeta in gemara or midrash - I heard a few times.

From an artistic perspective,  having two words looks better.

@magicker72 he is not asking about it.  He is asking why we have an extra את

@YDJ It's not extra. He's asking why it's included in the design.

Why wouldn’t they? What would you have assumed instead, and why?

Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34565/why-does-the-depiction-of-the-tablets-not-contain-the-full-wording

@YDJ TY, Posted an illustration.

One can answer that keeping Shabbos and honoring parents brings a person blessings, which is hinted by the word את. How so?
In the book "Wisdom of Hebrew Alphabet" by R. Munk, says in the prologue:
"In Devarim 11:26-28 we are asked to choose between blessing and curse:

רְאֵ֗ה אָנֹכִ֛י נֹתֵ֥ן לִפְנֵיכֶ֖ם הַיּ֑וֹם בְּרָכָ֖ה וּקְלָלָֽה׃ אֶֽת־הַבְּרָכָ֑ה אֲשֶׁ֣ר תִּשְׁמְע֗וּ אֶל־מִצְוֺת֙ יְהֹוָ֣ה אֱלֹֽהֵיכֶ֔ם אֲשֶׁ֧ר אָנֹכִ֛י מְצַוֶּ֥ה אֶתְכֶ֖ם הַיּֽוֹם׃ וְהַקְּלָלָ֗ה אִם־לֹ֤א תִשְׁמְעוּ֙ אֶל־מִצְוֺת֙ יְהֹוָ֣ה אֱלֹֽהֵיכֶ֔ם וְסַרְתֶּ֣ם מִן־הַדֶּ֔רֶךְ אֲשֶׁ֧ר אָנֹכִ֛י מְצַוֶּ֥ה אֶתְכֶ֖ם הַיּ֑וֹם לָלֶ֗כֶת אַחֲרֵ֛י אֱלֹהִ֥ים אֲחֵרִ֖ים אֲשֶׁ֥ר לֹֽא־יְדַעְתֶּֽם׃
See, this day I set before you blessing and curse: blessing, if you obey the commandments of your God יהוה that I enjoin upon you this day; and curse, if you do not obey the commandments of your G-d Hashem, but turn away from the path that I enjoin upon you this day and follow other gods, whom you have not experienced.

Regarding the blessing the emphatic article אֶת is used, while regarding curse אֶת is omitted, (but we have וְהַ). Midrash Vayikra Rabba 35:1 teaches that אֶת denotes the blessing:

Rabbi Abba son of Rabbi Ḥiyya said in the name of Rabbi Yonatan: I calculated blessings, I calculated curses; the blessings are from alef through tav, the curses are from vav through heh. Moreover, they are reversed. Rabbi Avin said: [God says:] ‘If you merit, I will transform the curses into blessings for you. When? When you observe My Torah.’ That is what is written: “If you follow My statutes.”

Regarding blessings for keeping Shabbos, there are many sources, such as Shemos Rabba 25:12. Regarding blessings for honoring parents, one is blessed with long life as in Shemos 20:12.

Looks like you are explaining why את is in the Torah. The OP is asking about art (hence: In the common representation of the Mosaic Tablets...).

@magicker72 we all know how to count till 2 and such an artistic representation is not a question about Judaism.

Indeed, it's a silly question.

@shmosel the OP knows the rules of this cite and deserves to be judged on the side of merit.
